# jQuery mobile popup height

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

We have some popup on our jQuery mobile page.

There is a link, what is triggers a popup, and we loaded the "terms and conditions" into this by jQuery. That is great, poup is fit to window size, scrollbar is there.

When I am seeing the DOM inspector, I see, jquery mobile set the element `height: 517px`.

User close the popup, and want to push on order, but there is an error, so we just want to show him an "error occured" message in the same popup. But for some reason, the height is not updated, there is the big `517px` popup with the little error message.

Of course, I tried to search the net, how to reset a popup.

Here is a question on SO, what has no accepted answer, but in the comments somebody mentioned this, what I've tried without success, the second popup height still remains.

```
 $('[data-role="popup"]').on("popupafterclose", function () {});
```

Comment: `$('[data-role="popup"]').on("popupafterclose", function () { $(this).removeAttr("style"); });`

Comment: Add this as an answer to accept it please.